# Reverse SSL_CLIENT_S_DN order in Apache?

Tags: openssl, mod-ssl

For some odd reason, mod_nss makes the client DN look like this: 
SSL_CLIENT_S_DN=C=SE,DC=FOO,serialNumber=123456789012,CN=BAR BAZ

Mod_ssl however makes it look like this: 
SSL_CLIENT_S_DN=/CN=BAR BAZ/serialNumber=123456789012/DC=FOO/C=SE

I think this could be what breaks the application; it works just fine with mod_ssl. What would be the easiest way to reverse the order?